# Should a Domain Object receive a list or elements of a list?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Say I have a Domain Object, which represents a Customer with a list of Offers.

Say I want to add a collection of Offers.  I believe I have two options:

**Option 1**

Have the Domain Object calculate the offers and then add them:

```
 public IEnumerable<IProduct> GetEligibleOffers(IOfferCalculator offerCalculator, IList<IProduct> products)
    {
        return offerCalculator.CalculateEligibility(Gender, Expenditure, products);
    }

    //Refactored this method.  
    public void AssignOffers(IList<IProduct> eligibleProducts)
    {
        foreach (var product in products)
        {
            _assignedProducts.Add(product);
        }
    }
```

**Option 2**

Have the Application Service calculate the offers and pass them to the Domain Object one by one.  Therefore the domain object will look like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IProduct> GetEligibleOffers(IOfferCalculator offerCalculator, IList<IProduct> products)
        {
            return offerCalculator.CalculateEligibility(Gender, Expenditure, products);
        }

        //Refactored this method to only accept one product
        public void AddOffer(IProduct eligibleProduct)
        {
            _assignedProducts.Add(eligibleProduct);
        }
```

In this case; the application service gets the eligible offers (using: CalculateEligibility) and then passes them one by one to the domain object (Customer.AssignOffer).

I am trying to decide, which approach to use (I realise both approaches will work).  Option one seems like the most appropriate. However, every example I can find online seems to use option 2 e.g. this [one](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Supplier.cs) and this [one](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/blob/master/src/NHibernate.DomainModel/Northwind/Entities/Order.cs). Therefore I wonder if option two is frowned upon for some reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, **don't overthink this** - this is merely a matter of taste, nothing else. Remember, the generic `List` in C# offers an `AddRange` as well as an `Add` method for convenience (I am actually wondering why you did not use it in your first example), so there is nothing which hinders you to design your domain objects similar, with *both* methods, one for adding single objects, one for adding a collection. This is actually something I would recommend in case you want to design your domain objects to handle all collections in a uniform manner.

However, if you are not sure if you will ever need both methods, and uniformness is not your goal, just implement the method you need first, and when it later turns out you could use something like an `AddRange` more than once, you can still refactor and add another method afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for that.  +1 for the reference to AddRange.  I will rename the method and remove the for loop.

Comment: I don't need to remove offers at the moment.  Therefore I don't have a remove method.  Is it normal to leave the Remove method? Again every example I look at online has an add and a remove.

Comment: @w0051977: same as a above - don't overthink this; add "Remove" now if your goal is uniformness; if not, add it when you need it.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I could add a remove method that accepts an Offer and the clear method, which empties the list?

Comment: @w0051977: whatever suits your requirements. Did I forget to say "don't overthink this"? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it depends:-) The key is whether the offer is separated aggregate root. If it is, use Application Service as rule of thumb of aggregate root is **not reference another entity** directly, but [use global id](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2020371&seqNum=4) instead. Otherwise, use domain object.